# application.css showing "Unknown property"

Tags: java, css, javafx

```
#Random {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    -fx-font-famiy: arial;
    -fx-border-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    -fx-border-radius: 20;
    -fx-border-width: 20px;
}
```

I am running a JavaFX project and using this CSS code. Whenever I run it, the eclipse IDE says that it is an unknown property. In addition, there is no pop-up menu when I am typing the code.

Comment: You have a very small typo `fx-font-famiy` should be `fx-font-family`.

Comment: Yeah but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't know about JavaFX-specific CSS properties. Just ignore the IDE warnings/errors. If it works when you run the application then you're good to go.

Comment: But there is no pop-up menu though

Comment: I watched a video of a guy using eclipse with CSS and he had some of the CSS properties show up. Whenever I type, there is no pop-up menu at all.